# RecordLinkage Column Errors On Very Large Dataset - Matching on Just 2 variables

Tags: r, record-linkage

I am working on a project to use RecordLinkage in R Studio to fuzzy merge two very large datasets.

My two datasets *set1* and *set2* have a different number of variables, but I need to link the data based on two columns with columns called "Address" and "housestring." However, I have a total of around twenty variables that are either in both datasets or in *set1*, but not *set2*.

The previous questions on this site suggest creating new sets with just the columns that I want to match - however, I cannot lose the other variables in my process.

Here is my code:

```
RLBigDataLinkage(set1, set2, identity1=NA, identity2=NA, exclude=colname("zillow_id","comment","housenumber","unit","city","postalcode","district","state","id","random","Street","City","housestreet","fulladdress","parcelid","propertyid","usecode","latitude","longitude","housenumberfraction","streetdirectionprefix", "streetname","streetsuffix","streetdirectionsuffix","unitprefix","zipplusfour","street"), strcmp=TRUE,strcmpfun=jarowinkler)
```

Even though I have excluded all of the mismatched columns from consideration, but I still get the error that *set1* and *set2* have different number of columns.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: I got this error when the `length(identity1)` is different than the number of rows in `set1`... Same for `identity2` and `set2`.  My fix was to provide an identity1 and 2 that were the same length as set1 and 2 respectively.